# How to select the dates between two dates in mySql

Tags: mysql

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` 
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '14.04.2022' AND '16.04.2022')
```

returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not how dates are formatted in MySQL. They should be `YYYY-MM-DD`, e.g. `2022-04-14'`

Comment: But my client has the dates in this format. Is there a way to get things to work?

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse them.

Comment: `where pickup_date between str_to_date('13.04.2022','%d.%m.%Y') and str_to_date('16.04.2022','%d.%m.%Y') `
 This is not showing me any results

Comment: What is the datatype of `pickup_date`?

Comment: It is varchar(255)

Comment: Is it also in the `dd.mm.yyyy` format? Then you also need `STR_TO_DATE(pickup_date, '%d.%m.%Y')`

Comment: It's best to store dates as `DATE` rather than strings. Then you can make use of indexes to make queries like this efficient.

Comment: Yeah, I will keep that in mind. And thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_field between str_to_date('14.04.2022','%d.%m.%Y') and str_to_date('16.04.2022','%d.%m.%Y')
```